# My vba code isn't working. Subscript out of range

Tags: vba

The VBA code below is supposed to 1) select a range of cells in another file 2)insert a new column in the active file 3)as it goes through each row in column C, it looks up the corresponding value in the range of cells in another file from #1 4) enters the value in the column next to the one it is looking up

However, it just isn't working and I'm not sure what is wrong being a newbie at this..
Please help.

```
Sub Translate()
Dim PartName As String
Dim CellName As String
Dim PartNameList As Range
Dim i As Integer

Set PartNameList = Workbooks("C:\Users\" "\Desktop\Part name translation.xlsx").Worksheets("Reference").Range("A1:B2000")

Worksheets("Initial").Columns("D").Insert
For i = 2 To Range("C2:C3000").Count
    If IsEmpty("C" & i) = True Then Exit For
    PartName = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("C" & i), PartNameList, 2, False)
    Range("C" & i).Value = PartName
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is it failing on?  I would guess (without running it) that it's the 'Set PartNameList = ' line.  I think you ought to only use the name of the workbook that is displayed in Excel's title bar when that workbook is selected.

Comment: Can't you just use the vlookup function from within Excel and fill down?  That's all this code appears to be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing a valid workbook name:

```
 Set PartNameList = Workbooks( _
    "C:\Users\" "\Desktop\Part name translation.xlsx"). _
    Worksheets("Reference").Range("A1:B2000")
```

It seems you are missing an Environment variable, this should fix it:

```
dim uName as String: uName = Environ("Username")
Set PartNameList = Workbooks( _
    "C:\Users\" & uName & "\Desktop\Part name translation.xlsx"). _
    Worksheets("Reference").Range("A1:B2000")
```

But, if the workbook is already open, you don't need to fully qualify it like that, you can just use the filename:

```
Set PartNameList = _
   Workbooks("Part name Translation.xlsx").Worksheets("Reference").Range("A1:B2000")
```

And finally, if the workbook is not open, I think you will need to open it, firstly:

```
dim uName as String: uName = Environ("Username")
dim wbPartName as Workbook
Set wbPartName = Workbooks.Open( _
    "C:\Users\" & uName & "\Desktop\Part name translation.xlsx")
Set partNameList = wbPartName.Worksheets("Reference").Range("A1:B2000")
```

Comment: Thank you David. However, I'm getting an error "Unable to get the Vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class" on "PartName = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("C" & i), PartNameList, 2, False)"

Comment: You're welcome, do consider marking this answer as "Accepted" so that others can benefit from it.  Your follow-up should should be a new question, but likely culprit is that you have not fully qualified `Range("C" & i)`, that a different workbook is `Active` at run-time, etc.